# Bootstrap Modal dialog - footer should be at bottom of printing page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I use a dialog in my application which shows content and also a footer. 
When the user print out the page (by pressing button **Print Modal**), this footer should be at bottom of printing page:

```
<div class="footer">
   This should be the footer at printing page
</div>
```

but it is at the bottom of the dialog. 
My question now would be if there is a possibility to move the footer at the bottom of the page?

[My Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/cvfz3vwL/77/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly hard problem, and I think there is no easy answer to it. However, I was able to get the behaviour you wanted by using `vh` units:

```
@media print {
  .control {
    display: none;
  }
  .footer {
    top: 100vh !important; /*position below the bottom of the page*/
    margin-top: -30px; /*move back up by the height of the footer*/
  }
}
```

You could also use `calc()` for this, instead of the negative margin:

```
@media print {
  .control {
    display: none;
  }
  .footer {
    top: calc(100vh - 30px) !important;
  }
}
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5uuj9m9L/)

Comment: Thanks a lot Jacob, you are great. I almost become desperate of this  problem!

Comment: @user3318489 np :D Just note that this answer might not have the best browser support, and I'd recommend testing it in a few different browsers before using on anything important

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head and quick fix. If you know the type of page of the print e.g. A4 (8.3 x 11.7 in), Letter (8.5 x 11 in) etc. Then add the following class in the `@media print` query and set the bottom according to the print page size. For the fiddle you shared and the print settings on my system. the following bottom negative margin inside the @media print did the trick.

```
.footer {
    bottom: -650px  !important;
}
```

Hope this helps

[Edit - **jQuery Solution**]

Here is a jquery solution that automatically calculates the margins by subtracting the modal height from the print page height to adjust the footer for the print. Do as follows:

Remove the `.footer` class with neg bottom from the `@media print` query.

Add jquery script cdn to the page. Change the onClick attribute of the print button as follows

```
<button onClick="javascript:PrintPage();" type="button" class="btn btn-default printButton">Print Modal</button>
```

Add the following function within the script tag right at the end.

```
function PrintPage()
{
   var ftr = $(".footer");
   var modalHeight = $(".modal-dialog").height();
   var newBottom = (892-modalHeight); //based on A4 page size height in pixels at 72 dpi (842) + margins (40px) . Adjust both as required.
   ftr.css("top","+=" + newBottom); // Add the empty calculated value in the top margin of the footer
   window.print(); // open print dialog
   ftr.css("top","-=" + newBottom); // reset the footer back to original position in html.
}
```

Hope this solution helps.

Comment: Thanks! My problem ist that the content (height) of the modal can change, so its dynamic content, and than this influences the possition of the footer: http://jsfiddle.net/cvfz3vwL/78/